# how to change back narrow and change color in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styling

i want to change color in action bar and change the back narrow icon. its work when i just change the back narrow, but when i'm styling the color in actionbar, icon is gone. i want to change color of actionbar to blue color.

this is my code in xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.


-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.

    -->
</style>

<style name="AppBaseAlternativeTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppAlternativeTheme" parent="AppBaseAlternativeTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="CustomUpIndicatorTheme" parent="AppAlternativeTheme">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_up_indicator</item>
</style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this Using following Code in Activity.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_actionbar_screen_back);
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar_background_color)));
```

Answer (score 2):

try it-

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```